# Is it considered bad practice to use a sentinal value of "-1" in a returned object if a query returned no values?

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code in my DataModel.cs class:

```
    public User ValidateUser(string Username, string Password)
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext();

                var query = from u in db.Users where (u.Username == Username && u.Password == Password) select u;

                if (query.Count() != 0)
                {
                    return query.First();
                }
                else
                {
                    return new User { UserID = -1 };
                }
    }
```

I have a login class calling this on my DataModel, checking to see if a user is valid.  If the user is valid than I want to have a reference to that "logged-in" user in my login class (which is why ValidateUser returns a user object).

Right now, if that user doesn't exist or the password is wrong, I simply return an empty User object with the id set to -1 to flag it as being not a real user.

Is this bad practice?

How should I handle this case?  If ValidateUser just returned a bool it wouldn't be a problem but because I also need a reference to that user I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: Not related to the main question, but in your code you are executing the query twice; first one time to count the number of results, then again to get the first item of the result. Use the FirstOrDefault method instead, so that you don't make two database calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, this is bad practice, because it is implicit. If nothing is returned, the method should return null. This is self-explanatory.

Or, if it needs to be handled completely different as the normal case or needs additional information, you could consider to throw an exception.

Comment: Arguably null is also a kind of "magic number", and still implicit. If the user does not exist, the method cannot do its job (return a User object), hence it should throw an exception. Less error-prone than returning null.

Comment: @sleske, this is the sort of thing null is intended for. Sure, it's a "magic number" but it can't be mistaken for a valid User because it's not a User object.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just return null but if you want a sentinal value at least make it a value on the User object:

```
public class User
{
    // ... User class goes here

    public static readonly User NullUser = new User();
}

public User ValidateUser(string Username, string Password)
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();

    var user = db.Users FirstOrDefault(u.Username == Username);

    return user ?? User.NullUser;
}
```

With the sentinal value at this level you don't have to look inside the result to check if its invalid or not. This is a version of the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

You could return null or throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally return `null` to indicate a failed search, though it's reasonable to return -1 if you're returning an `int` index (like `Array.Find` or something).

In this case, though, your method name is `ValidateUser` - which implies a `bool` result. So, I'd go with the `TryParse` convention of an out parameter:

```
 bool ValidateUser(string username, string password, out User user);

 User u;
 if (!ValidateUser(username, password, out u)) {
    // user does not validate, and u is still null
 }
```

Or, change the method name to something like `GetUser` or `LoginUser` to make it clear that it's not a `true/false` proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Technically that is an anti pattern known as magic numbers

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Another programmer could very easily consume your method and think this was valid:

```
public bool DoesUserExist(string u, string p)
{
     return ValidateUser(u,p) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with something more traditional like having my User class implement [IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity_members.aspx) so the consumer could call IsAuthenticated on my user rather than checking some sentinel value from my DAL.

Answer (score 0):

Returning -1 only makes sense when you are returning an index.